# How to merge WindowsUpdates into Windows 7 installation ISO

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have Windows 7 install ISO. I use it to install test environment.

The problem is that I need to reinstall the environment often. And each time I have to install all the updates via WindowsUpdate.

I can see that each time the updates are downloaded to `%WINDIR%\SoftwareDistribution\Download\`

How can I merge these updates to the ISO file so they are installed all together?

Comment: HowToGeek has a great artikle: http://www.howtogeek.com/124368/how-to-create-a-customized-windows-7-installation-disc-with-integrated-updates/

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the files from `%WINDIR%\SoftwareDistribution\Download`.

Use [WSUSOffline](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) to get all required updates. Install the Deployment Tools from the [Windows ADK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652). Now mount the `Install.wim` from your DVD to a drive like `C:\7work\Mount`. Copy all updates to a folder like `C:\7work\updates`.

Now run `DISM /Image:C:\7work\Mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\7work\updates`. This adds all updates into the image. Use `DISM /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\7work\Mount /commit` to save the changes and unmount the WIM.